# Tornado get input from URL request

Tags: python-3.x, api, tornado

My program is to get parameter(URL) from web and in my tornado API, i want to accept them into one bye one. Now my code accepts a single tuple. My api want to fetch the 4 parameters(south-lat,south-long,east-lat,east-long) which comes from the web URL request. And i will implement them into get method of Tornado and find them in my database. I want to know how to accept them in tornado in seperately. This is my current working codes.

```
import socket
import tornado.web
from datetime import datetime
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
from tornado.options import define,options

#apicall/v1/geoloc.json?geoquery=True&southwest_lat=''&southwest_lng=''&northeast_lat=''&northeast_lng=''

#tornado port
port = 8088
host = "127.0.0.1"

#make a connection with mongodb
#client=MongoClient()

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("hello APIs")

#what this works is here   
class VisualizationHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self,*args):#how to accept the input from map?


        self.open_args=args
        #self.open_kwargs=kwargs

        print(self.open_args)
        print(type(self.open_args))

        #self.write("Data is at the terminal")
        #client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
        #db=client.test
        #docs=db.neighborhoods.findOne()
        #if docs is None:
            #print("Not found")
        #else:
            #print(docs)

            #lat=self.get_argument('lat',True)
            #long=self.get_argument('long',True)
            #self.write(lat)
            #self.write(long)



        #var neighborhood = db.neighborhoods.findOne( { geometry: { $geoIntersects: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ slong, slat] } } } } )

def main():
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
        (r"/geo/(.*)",VisualizationHandler),
    ])

    try:
        sockets = tornado.netutil.bind_sockets(port, address=host)
        print("Socket binding successful to {0}:{1}".format(host, port))
    except socket.error:
        print("Socket binding failed to {0}:{1}".format(host, port))
        return

    try:
        _id = tornado.process.fork_processes(0, max_restarts=3)
        print("Process forked : {}".format(_id))

        server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
        server.add_sockets(sockets)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt: # stop with Ctrl+C from shell
        print("Tornado is stopping")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Tornado is starting")

    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get() method's args/kwargs are retrieved from the url (url regex's match groups, to be specific). Of course, you can create something like this to pass arguments to your function:

```
(r"/geo/(.*)/(.*)", VisualizationHandler)
```

or

```
(r"/geo/(?P<south_lat>.*)/(?P<south_long>.*)", VisualizationHandler)
```

and args/kwargs south_lat and south_long would be passed to your function from a URL like /geo/123/456, but it's inconvenient. I'd advise you to pass your arguments as URL params /geo?south_lat=123&south_long=456 and read them using get_argument().

Comment: class VisualizationHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        lat=self.get_argument('lat')
        long=self.get_argument('long')

        print("lat " + lat)
        print("long " + long)

my handler call is like (r"/geo/(?P<lat>.*)/(?P<long>.*)",VisualizationHandler)! 
It got error when i access from URL like the way u said!

Comment: What URL are you accessing? What error are you getting?

Comment: like the way /geo?south_lat=123&south_long=456 ! it got error (404 not found!)

Comment: If you use `/geo?south_lat=123&south_long=456` you should setup router with a setting like `(r"/geo(.*)", VisualizationHandler)`.

Comment: Thanks Sir! I got it now!

Comment: sir! If I want to validate the arguments parameters in my script, what exception error should I need to raise?

Comment: The tornado.web.HTTPError class. `raise HTTPError(400, "Your error text")`

Comment: is there any ways to write json object in tornado? sir